# How do a sort a array of void* that points to places with names?

Tags: c, qsort

Basically there are rectangles (buildings) and circles (people).

The task I need to do is basically, when a function "fg" is called, every circle that is inside a given radius needs to run to the closest rectangle, and after all the circles inside the radius finds a rectangle, I need to report on a .txt file the names of the circles that run to each rectangle sorted alphabetically.

Such as:

Rectangle A:
c1
c2
c3

Rectangle B:
c7
c11
c20

...

And so on...

I need to store the addresses of the circles that run, on a vector of each rectangle.
I tried to use qsort from stdlib.h, but maybe the function that i use to compare is wrong

(EDIT - full code to better understand):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct wow{
    char* name;

}wow_t;

const char* getName(const void* pointer){
    const wow_t* aux = pointer;
    return aux->name;
}

int myCompare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    // setting up rules for comparison
    const char* temp1 = getName(a);
    const char* temp2 = getName(b);
    return strcmp(temp1, temp2);

}


int main() {
    
    wow_t temp[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        temp[i].name = calloc(30, 1);
    }

    strcpy(temp[0].name, "Joe");
    strcpy(temp[1].name, "Daniel");
    strcpy(temp[2].name, "Rhuan");
    strcpy(temp[3].name, "Drake");
    strcpy(temp[4].name, "Peter");

    void* aux[5];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        aux[i] = &temp[i];
    }   
    puts("Before: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("aux[%d] = %s\n", i, getName(aux[i]));
    }   


    qsort(aux, 5, sizeof(const void*), myCompare);

    puts("After: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("aux[%d] = %s\n", i, getName(aux[i]));
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter needs to be the size of the actual array elements:

```
qsort(aux, 5, sizeof *aux, myCompare);
```

Also, since your array elements are of type `void *`, the pointers passed to the comparison function are pointers to them.  So you want:

```
int myCompare(const void* a, const void* b) {
    // setting up rules for comparison
    const char* temp1 = getName(*(const void **)a);
    const char* temp2 = getName(*(const void **)b);
    return strcmp(temp1, temp2);

}
```